# Compare growth rate for different sized samples

Tags: mean, pre-post-comparison

I have 11 years of membership data for a denomination of churches and I want to find the top 20 growth rate "trend breakers".

In my current method I have:

1. calculated % change from the previous year for all churches
2. calculated 3yr, 5yr and 10yr averages
3. determined the overall mean for each of these
4. filtered out below avg scores for 10y, 5y, and then 3y

This stil leaves me with a list of more than 20.

I have two questions:

1. Is there a more scientific way to identify the top twenty trendbreakers?
2. On what basis can I filter out small churches with explosive but short-term growth that inflates their growth average?

Answer (score 1):

It's good that you already recognize that [growth can more easily be explosive off a small baseline](https://xkcd.com/1102/).

I'd recommend that you start with a plot. Plot growth rates on the vertical axis (best to use *geometrical* means of year-over-year growths, which is just the 10th root of the overall 11-year growths for those churches where you have data for all 11 years) against initial membership on the horizontal axis. Then you can remove smaller churches based on the plot and finally pick the top 20 of the remainder.